# Ouput a given voltage from a PIC18F4550

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

How can I get a constant voltage out of the A port (or any other port) of a PIC18F4550 chip? 
I don't want to use PWM.

```
void main() {
    adcon1 = 0x00;
    trisa = 0x00;
    for(;;) {
        //how to put 2.5v at porta.b0 (or any other voltage on any other port)?
    }
}
```

Comment: The 18f4550 can run at 2.5 volts. If you were to do so then making the pin high would output 2.5 V. This may make interfacing with other hardware more complex if it's at a different level

Comment: How?..  Without PWM?..  Buy a DAC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get a constant voltage out of the A port of a PIC18F4550 chip? I don't want to use PWM.

Since the PIC 18F4550 does not have a built-in D/A, you can only output digital voltages directly.  These can only be Vss or Vdd.

"Don't want to" is not a valid engineering reason, so low pass filtered PWM is the next obvious choice if you need more than two levels.  PWM has the advantage of being highly linear and monotonic, and can be configured for different resolutions.  The only real drawback is that resolution is traded off with speed.  The more resolution you want, the slower you have to go.  However, if the built-in PWM can achieve a combination of speed and resolution that works for your application, then that is the way to go.

Otherwise, you have to add external D/As.  There are many available, with digital interfaces that include parallel, SPI, and IIC.  Mircochip, among many others, makes such D/As suitable for connecting to microcontrollers.

Comment: +1 especially for "don't want to is not an engineering reason"

Answer (score 1):

Olin has it right, but if you *really* mean *constant*  -- i.e., you *only* need 2.5V and will never require any other voltage, you can actually use simple voltage division, and might require a voltage follower as a buffer depending on what you're trying to drive.

Another approach, now that I think of it, would be a switched capacitor circuit, in which a clock frequency can be changed to alter the effective resistance of a switched cap circuit.  You would need to filter out your clock frequencies.  This approach, though, is far more problematic than PWM -- to the point of I couldn't begin to understand why you would want to do this.